# How was Stormbreaker able to withstand the power of an Infinity Stone?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War* Thor throws *Stormbreaker* at Thanos, while Thanos uses an Infinity Stone to counter Stormbreaker but fails to stop it.

How did Stormbreaker withstand the power of an Infinity Stone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shadow Wizard answered it quite well but in writer's  own words:

> When asked how can Stormbreaker overpower the power of the completed Infinity Gauntlet, writers Christopher Markus and Stephen McFeely suggest that Eitri is responsible because of his "Dwarven magic": He made both items and made it so that Stormbreaker is able to defeat the Infinity Gauntlet. -  [wikia](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Stormbreaker#cite_ref-2)

Video for the same interview:

Answer (score 21):

> How did Stormbreaker withstand the power of an infinity stone?

Because it was forged from [Uru metal](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Uru) which is the same metal used to forge the [Infinity Gauntlet](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Infinity_Gauntlet).

And since the Gauntlet can harness the power of the stones, surely it means the metal is resistant to their power.